# JUnit Format in WebDriver vs WebDriver Backed

Tags: selenium, junit4

I have recorded a test case in Selenium IDE and want to convert that to Junit. When I try to change through format, I have two options called ‘JUnit WebDriver’ and ‘JUnit WebDriver Backed’. Can you guys please explain me what is the different between this WebDriver and WebDriver Backed? Sorry I am new to Selenium, started learning through Internet Materials.

Thanks, 
Abdul Hameed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You use "JUnit WebDriver" if you are using the Selenium 2/WebDriver API. You use "JUnit WebDriver Backed" if you are using the Selenium 1/RC API.

If you switch back and forth you can see the difference in the test method displayed in the IDE window.

More info on the Selenium website [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#webdriver-backed-selenium-rc).

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. If you have existing code of Selenium RC (Selenium 1) and you want to switch it is better and easier to convert into "JUnit WebDriver Backed" by creating an instance as below:
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);

Answer (score 2):

The WebDriver Backed JUnit is a hybrid option to allow you continue using the Selenium 1.0 RC while migrating your existing tests to Selenium 2.0 WebDriver